# Why is Git trying to connect to the wrong host?

Tags: git

I have a LAMP system setup on CentOS. I also have git setup on the same server with a [centralized workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-centralized) (we have just moved over from SVN). I have multiple repositories now cloned around the system, using the following syntax:

```
git clone git:someexistingrepository.git
```

This is working fine. Now, I had an existing directory I wanted to convert in to a git working direcory. I followed the instructions from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus). As I have been using the local server, I used the following command:

```
git remote add origin git:myrepo.git
```

`myrepo.git` was already setup with:

```
git init --bare myrepo.git
```

I have done this before and I've not had any problems, however this time I did, when I ran:

```
git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'git (173.192.58.115)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b1:43:2f:b0:7e:2f:ba:74:6f:19:2e:b8:35:81:10:b6.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? ^C
```

I looked up that IP address and it is apparently one used by `git.co.uk` - obviously nothing to do with me (or Git). Is there some weird behaviour happening here, or can anyone suggest some incorrect config I may have? I read that using `git:reponame.git` was the right way (I'm afraid I can't find the SO question I read this on sorry) - is this so?

**Update**

Note: I'm using the SSH protocol, not git. Also, the `config` file inside `.git` looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git:somerepo.git
```

This **is the same** for both the cloned repositores and ones using the method described above, so I don't know why one is resolving to that host and one isn't. Using `git://` gives the (expected) error:

```
git clone git://bugs.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/bugs/.git/
fatal: Unable to look up  (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
```

**Update 2**

Thanks to the hints and answer from Oskar N, and that I realised that the root user had this problem whereas other users hadn't, I finally realised that I'd originally set something up in /etc/skel...

```
[user@host ~]$ cat .ssh/config
Host git
        Hostname localhost
        User git
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

So, git *was* the host (and the answer correct, thanks!). When I ran `resolveip` I was in the root screen, adding something to `/var/www/` as it's all owned by root. Luckily my other sites are setup with users.

Comment: I don't why it resolves differently, but I'm pretty sure the issue is the "git:" part of the url. I've edited my answer for ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repository is a URL. The "git:" part means it should lookup the hostname "git", which on your system resolves to git.co.uk.   I believe the SO question you saw actually used `git://` which means to use the git protocol.

For SSH you should use either `ssh://user@hostname/path/to/reponame.git` for absolute paths or `user@hostname:path/to/reponame.git` for relative paths. If you're cloning on the same system, simply use `reponame.git` as the URL.

Comment: See my question for a further *facepalm* update! Thanks to your answer and comments I realised the problem, and seeing as the problem was local to me you're absolutely right. Thanks!