# How to create a repository for a subfolder of an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, subdirectory

I have a relatively big project (a specific version of ns3 all-in-one, e.g. ns-allinone-3.20), containing several modules. I want to keep the src folder of one of these modules (module ns-3.20 which is a subfolder under project's root folder, and it's the parent of my target src folder) in a repository. I don't know if it is possible to keep only the src folder on a repository (let's say Bitbucket/git) and do the control version just for this subfolder, since there are too many files in the whole project domain that will be modified whenever a recompile happens. Therefore, there will be too many unnecessary push/pull for executable files.

In addition, I want to do this subfolder version control via eclipse. I already know how to create a whole project with bitbucket and eclipse. But, I don't know how to have a project in eclipse and control just one subdirectory via git in the eclipse.

I appreciate any hint/help on this.

Comment: I think you're asking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774).  Yes?

Comment: Any files that would be modified when the code is compiled should be ignored by your version control system, so that should not be one of your concerns.