# Push changes from non-git directory to a non-empty git repository

Tags: git, github

I downloaded an existing Git Project (instead of cloning it). I have made some changes to the code. Now I want to push the changes to the existing repository.

I saw some examples ([Github guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus), [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus)) but they all assume that remote repository is empty.

In my case, the remote repository is not empty. I want to push just the additional code (diff) on top of a certain branch. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a .git folder?

Comment: Nope. I downloaded a particular branch of the project. The .git directory is not present in the download.

Answer (score 1):

I think that easiest way to do it would be cloning existing repository,then checking out the same branch, and then copying files changed in non-git directory to your git project directory, and then  commit them.

Comment: I.e. why would you use a fork to eat a soop. Good answer