# How to add existing project to Git with TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

This it the TortoiseGit version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus)

If I have an existing project and I want to add add it to Git version control and "check it out" immediately, what's the TortoiseGit command for that?

I searched in *tortoisegit "create repository here"* and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the context menu of the main folder and select "Git Create repository here...". And commit all files (don't forget to add files you don't want to track to the ignore list).

Comment: Is there some kind of "default" way to get your ignore list setup? Like for a Visual C++ MFC project rather than doing it manually?

Comment: See here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html

Comment: If you are having problems finding the option on windows 11, don't forget to expand the context menu in order to see all the options. The "'Git Create repository here'' option is hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

Is TortoiseGit required ? Because you could just open a command line, go to project dir and execute 'git init .'