# How to convert existing non-empty directory into a Git working directory and push files to a remote branch

Tags: git

I have non empty folder with project.
I want to push not to the master but to the branch . How to do this?

```
cd <folder>
git init
git remote add origin <url> //at this point my folder connected to the master
```

What should be next?

```
git branch <branch1>
git add .
git commit -m "commint to branch1"
git push
```

Comment: Does "branch1" exist on the remote `origin` or do you need to create it?

Comment: @Richard, need to create.

Comment: And the obvious question: have you done a `pull` or ` fetch` to get everything already in the remote?

Comment: *"What should be next?"* -- first thing to do after you add a remote or change the URL of an existing remote is [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch). It gets on the local repo the information about the commits and branches present on the remote repo.

Comment: @Richard, no currently did not done pull, fetch.

Comment: You can `git fetch` to get information from the remote, then `git checkout -b <new branch>` to create the new branch. Then add, commit and push (then maybe pull to check everything is OK).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert existing non-empty directory into a Git working directory and push files to a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've not done a `git fetch` you don't have the changes from the remote in any branches including the one you've created. Assuming you want to use `branch1` as the name in the remote. I would suggest

- Backup your local repository (copy the `.git` folder somewhere else)
- Switch to `master`

  ```
  git checkout master
  ```
- Rename your local working branch for the time being

  ```
  git branch -m branch1 tempBranch
  ```
- Get the content of the remote locally

  ```
  git fetch
  ```
- Ensure your `master` is up to date with `origin/master`

  ```
  git pull
  ```
- Create a new working branch and set it up in the origin

  ```
  git checkout -b branch1
  git push -u origin branch1
  ```
- Put the changes you wanted into the real branch1

  ```
  git merge tempBranch
  ```

  you may need to handle conflicts at this point.
- Push your changes

  ```
  git push
  ```

Alternatively, if you've only made trivial changes, just start anew with a clean clone of the remote and redo you changes in that new local repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following commands :

```
git checkout -b <branch1>
git add .
git commit -m "commint to branch1"
git push -u origin <branch1>
```