# My Github repo has 'main' and 'master' branches - what is their purpose?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was trying to push some local unversioned code into a repo and get it up onto GitHub for accessibility reasons.

I followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus)

```
cd <local_dir>
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Then I created a new repo on github and did

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/...
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git push --force-with-lease
```

But I now see on github that I have 2 branches 'main' and 'master'
I guess github created 'main' when it created the repo and I created 'master' when I synced from my local repo

Do I need both?

Can I just merge master into main and then delete master?

At present it is just confusing me

**Note**: I have now tried (locally)

```
git branch -m master main
git push origin HEAD
```

but I'm getting an error

```
To https://github.com/<the-repo>
 ! [rejected]          HEAD -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<the-repo>'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Whatt am I missing?

Comment: Yes, you can. Git uses `master` as the name of the default branch. Github decided to change it `main` recently. You can choose to pick either.

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 9):

After events of 2020 in the USA, GitHub decided to rename the default Git branch `main` ([details](https://www.theregister.com/2020/06/15/github_replaces_master_with_main)). Git and GitHub do not enforce any branch name, but a repository needs a default branch; how this branch is named is up to you.

As for your 2nd question, settling on `main` is fine. Before doing any changes, check on which branch your commits are :

- if you made your commits on `master`, you'll have to merge `master` to `main`, then delete `master`
- if you made your commits on `main`, there is nothing on `master` and and can delete it.

You can :

- do this on your workstation and `push` changes to GitHub (my preferred choice)
- work on GitHub and `pull` from there

EDIT to answer the extra question :
Git is great in that it has fairly informative error messages with suggestions :

- `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.`
  This means the remote branch (on GitHub) has changes your local branch has not, which is why Git refuses to `push`.
- `Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`
  This is the typical solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you choose `master`, you'll need to go into the repository setting's and set it to be the "default branch" before you can delete `main`. I believe it will complain if you try to delete it while it's marked as the default.

Comment: I've added an update on the end of the original question. Would appreciate further comments on that if possible?

Comment: How does GitHub decided which branch names is the default? How does it react if there is a `main` and `master` branch in a repo? Which one is treated as default and shown on the projects landing page?

Comment: @buhtz there is an option in the repository's _Settings -> Branches_ section, it's called literally _Default branch_ - you need to click on "edit" and select a branch as default.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't **need** any specific branch.

Older versions of Git (and thus GitHub), used to create a "master" branch by default. In later versions (IIRC, around October 2020), the default branch was renamed to "main", in order to use more inclusive language.

From a technical perspective, you could keep both, decide on one, or even drop them both and decide your default branch is called SpongeBob.

Comment: As a relative newbie, sticking to a single name would be preferable for now. 'main' sounds good. So do i make that change locally and push the change to github?

Comment: @FeargalHogan yup, pretty much. You can rebase `main` on top of `master` to make sure you have all the commits you need, and them remove `master both locally and remotely (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/2422776 for some extra details)

Comment: GitHub have made that change already; the primary authors of Git itself have not. There's a technical reason: a bunch of stuff that needs to be fixed in the test suite first. I try to avoid touching the politics of this myself. :-)

Comment: Git's default branch is still called master. It is GitHub that made the change if you use their UI.

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing were this main or master showing in the folder/repo goto the view section click on hidden file and you found one file called .git just delete it and your problem will solve