# Unable to checkout on git remote server?

Tags: git

I initialized a remote ssh repo using `git init --bare` and added the following `post-receive` hooks

```
#!/bin/sh            

dest=/home/git/api
rm -rf $dest         
mkdir -p $dest       
GIT_WORK_TREE=$dest  
git checkout --force
```

The problem is i keep getting error

> remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

I don't understand this error where am i going wrong ?

Comment: You are trying to checkout in a bare repository, which is not possible. The error already states whats wrong.

Comment: Possibly [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456998/1665058) is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no work tree in a bare repository. So, you'll have to clone the repo and add the hook.