# GIT push - remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

Tags: git, laravel, version-control

I'm new to GIT.
I create repository with commands:

```
cd /home/user_name
mkdir repo && cd repo
mkdir site.git && cd site.git
git init --bare
```

then in the `hooks` directory, I create the `post-receive` file and add there:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/user_name/dev.ireserve.com --git-dir=/home/user_name/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

after that, I add permissions: `chmod +x post-receive`

at my local machine in the laravel project directory I run:

```
git init
```

then I run:

```
git remote add live ssh://root@example.com/home/user_name/repo/site.git
```

after that usually:

```
git add .
git commit -m "my message"
```

and at the end :

```
git push live master
```

but I got a message:

```
remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

[image]

Why I got this error? What is a problem?

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456923/why-am-i-getting-the-message-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree)

Comment: I don't think that this is depicted. I cant find an answer in the link you posted... Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: can you check if you have branches on your machine, `git branch -a`

Comment: Use [this guide](https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/)

Comment: @HamzaMohamed I got this: C:\wamp\www\mavis>git branch -a
* master
  remotes/live/master

C:\wamp\www\mavis>

Comment: @HCK I follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

Comment: I added an answer as apparently the answer that was picked, explains the Q, but doesn't show how to solve or show a toturial .. if you see it a satisfying answer, please mark as solved, otherwise please explain what is missing and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: I follow many tutorials but I dont know why I got : remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree ... I'm already in a work tree /mavis is my work tree ... there is also folder .git .

Comment: out of curiosity; why did you add Laravel tag?

Comment: my project is Laravel project ... and I have .htaccess file that redirect all to /public folder and maybe .htaceess file makes a problem

Comment: @AleksPer You steps seems ok. Is the machine with your laravel project different from the machine where site.git repo located? And since you used ssh protocol, please also make sure the ssh key is added in your local machine.

Comment: my fault... I select wrong folder ...

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, you have 1 directory on both sides, you need to start creating versions so you can use the real power of GIT.

You need to create branches(versions) if you are willing to use `GIT add`.

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456923/why-am-i-getting-the-message-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree)

for adding branches, check this [tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/18).

and this is the tutorial from the [start](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).

This is the best tutorial, IMHO; for GIT.

It will save a lot of effort and time.

Happy coding!

Comment: I follow many tutorials but I dont know why I got : remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree ... I'm already in a work tree /mavis is my work tree ... there is also folder .git ...

Comment: Usually the tutorials are using Gits that have already many branches, as they try to keep the tutorial suitable for every situation. just check the tutorial I have added, if you liked it and wanted to dive more .. you can always check the GIT [Doc](https://git-scm.com/doc)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: I think a `mkdir` step is missing from your Laravel setup instructions.

---

This command:

```
git init --bare
```

is meant for making *server* repositories in which *no one will ever do any work*.

Now, that might seem an odd thing to do: why create a repository where no one can work on the repository?  And it *is* an odd thing to do, but it exists for a reason.

#### Bare vs non-bare repository

If you make a repository where you *can* work:

```
git init
```

then you can work in it, but—to oversimplify a bit—no one else should *ever* just *send* you their work unannounced.  But people also need to *share* work, and one common usage pattern is that everyone agrees that some work-sharing repository, over on some central server such as the corporate "master source repository" machine, should be the place to which everyone sends work.

At the same time, though, you don't want to have to have someone who spends all day taking people's work into that central repository.  You want to let people send their work as soon as it's ready, so that everyone else can go to the central repository to *see* (or even obtain and use) their work *right away*.  So you need a place that peole *can* send their work, unannounced, *right now*.

That's a `--bare` repository.  Since no one works in it, you won't overwrite *their* in-progress work by sending your *completed* work.

#### This is really about the difference between a *commit* and a *work-tree*

Making a new commit makes a permanent and incorruptible<sup>1</sup> snapshot of your work.  But it has to get this from somewhere.  The minimum "somewhere" is found in other version control systems as the *work-tree:* the place you do your work.  Git inserts an extra wrinkle here, and forces you to know about it: it adds the *index*, also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache* (three names for one thing—it's a very important entity in Git!).  The index and work-tree come as a pair, though: they're where you can write things.  Commits, once made, are entirely unchangeable, which is what makes them incorruptible.  So you need a place to work, where you can both read *and write* files.

A bare repository holds commits—the read only snapshots—but has no work-tree.<sup>2</sup>  That's pretty much all there is to it: with no work-tree, there is no place to work.  That's what makes it suitable for pushing-to, but without a place to work, you can't do any work in it.  You'll need a non-bare repository as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>Commits are really only *mostly* permanent: they last as long as there are names by which one can find them.  I'll leave this detail for other tutorials.  They are entirely incorruptible though, because the true name of a commit is its hash ID.  The hash ID, while quite unpredictable in advance, is a cryptographic checksum of the *contents* of the commit.  If something goes wrong and a commit becomes corrupted, Git will notice, because the contents won't fit the true name hash ID any more.

<sup>2</sup>For somewhat silly implementation reasons, a bare repository still has an index.  It just has no work-tree.  They're paired—the index indexes (hence the name) the work-tree—but a bare repository typically still has a completely-empty index it carries around.

---

#### Some servers fake up a work-tree for a bare repository

You can combine the bare repository (with no work-tree) with Git's *hooks* mechanism to create a sort of fake work-tree.  This is how your Laravel setup is intended to work, for instance.  When your bare server receives a `git push`, the server runs the hook, and the hook runs `git --work-tree=<path> checkout -f` to set up a temporary work-tree in `<path>`.  This temporary work-tree is the work-tree for the duration of the one `git checkout` command.  (The index now indexes that temporary work-tree.)  Then the `git checkout` finishes and the bare repository continues to have no work-tree.  You still can't *work* in it.

Note that this last `git --work-tree=<path> checkout -f` won't *create* a directory `<path>`.  This directory must already exist.  It should initially be empty; after the first `git checkout -f`, it will contain what `git checkout` wrote; and on each later `git checkout -f`, Git will assume (via the index) that it contains whatever the *last* `git checkout -f` wrote, and update it in place based on this information.

Hence your original Laravel setup should have had a `mkdir home/user_name/dev.ireserve.com` in it.

Comment: Yes, init your own repository non-bare. Generally you will *clone* some repository (such as the central-server one), so as to start with all their commits, and to convert all their branch names to your remote-tracking names. This `git clone` process will do its own `git init`. Do `git clone` without `--bare` to make your clone non-bare.

Comment: If the repository you clone is completely empty (is a new one created with `git init --bare`), you'll get a warning at the end. In this particular case, you could have just done your own `git init --bare`. But it's better to start with `git clone` (and the warning), I think.

Comment: so at /home/user_name/repo/ to run git clone ?

Comment: On your machine, wherever you like. Note, by the way, that the hook on the target machine (where you run `git --work-tree=<path> checkout -f`) can't *create* the work-tree directory; it must already exist. That step appears to be missing from your Laravel setup directions.

Comment: but --work-tree=/home/user_name/dev.example.com is there - and there is my laravel project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166359/discussion-between-aleks-per-and-torek).

Comment: Your work repository and work-tree *must not* be the place that the server dumps its files into.

Comment: It's not clear what's printing `stdin: is not a tty` but whatever it is is trying to do something that doesn't work when not connected to a human.