# Merge on Raspberry Pi2 git server

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-remote, git-server

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I have configured a git server on my Raspberry PI 2 with the current Raspian Image (March 2018).

In my git repro I have two branches:

```
git@raspberrypi:~/database.git$ git branch
comments
*master
```

If I merge the 'comments' branch into the 'master' I get the following error message:

```
git@raspberrypi:~/database.git$ git merge comments
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you,

Marc

Comment: Is it possible that you're using a bare repository? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456923/why-am-i-getting-the-message-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree

Comment: As others have said, you appear to be using a bare repository.  It's not recommended or useful to make code changes inside of the bare repo.  Clone the repository elsewhere, make your changes, merge, and push back into the bare repo.

Comment: Thanks all, cloning the repro is the best way